# PDO query doesnt upload to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i'm buzy working on a registration script using PDO and I fixed everything in my opinion but the script doesnt upload anything to the server but the connection works. 
This is my code

```
<?php
if ( empty( $_POST ) ){
?>
<div class="registreren">
<form name="register" method="POST" action="registreren.php">
<p> Vul hier uw inloggegevens in: </p>
<input type='text' placeholder="E-mail" name="email" required >
<br>
<input type='password' placeholder="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" required>
<br>
<input type='password' placeholder="bevestig wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" required>
<br><br>
<p> Persoonlijke gegevens </p>
<input type='text' placeholder="Voornaam" name="voornaam" required>
<br>
<input type='text' placeholder="Achternaam" name="achternaam" required>
<br>
<input type='text' name="straat" placeholder="Straat" required>
<br>
<input type='text' name="huisnummer" placeholder="num" maxlength="5" size="1" required>
<input type='text' name="postcodenum" placeholder="1234AB" maxlength="6" size="6" required>
<br>
<input type='text' name="woonplaats" placeholder=woonplaats required>
<br> 
<input type='tel' name="telnum" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" maxlength="15" size="12" required>
<br><br>
<input type='submit' value="submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
} else {
$db_user = '##';
$db_pass = '##';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main_database', $db_user, $db_pass )
or die('Error connecting to mysql server');
$form = $_POST;
$email = $form[ "email" ];
$password = $form[ "wachtwoord" ];
$voornaam = $form["voornaam"];
$achternaam = $form[ "achternaam" ];
$straat = $form[ "straat" ];
$huisnummer = $form[ "huisnummer" ];
$postcode = $form[ "postcodenum" ];
$woonplaats = $form[ "woonplaats" ];
$telefoonnummer = $form[ "telnum" ];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( email, password, straat, huisnummer, postcode, woonplaats, voornaam,           achternaam, telefoonnummer ) VALUES ( :email, :password, :straat, :huisnummer :postcode, :woonplaats,   :voornaam, :achternaam, :telefoonnummer )";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':email'=>$email, ':password'=>$password, ':straat' =>$straat,':huisnummer' =>$huisnummer, ':postcode' => $postcode, ':woonplaats' => $woonplaats, ':voornaam'=>$voornaam, ':achternaam' =>$achternaam, ':telefoonnummer' => $telefoonnummer  ) );

}
?>
```

Could you guys please help me. Couldnt find anything out.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I got no error. That was my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos:

```
[..snip..]at, :huisnummer :postcode, :woonpl[..snip..]
                         ^---missing ,
```

Never EVER assume that a DB operation will succeed. Always check for failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise. If you'd checked the results of your `prepare()` call, you'd have gotten the syntax error notice.

There is exactly ONE way for an operation to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Yet everyone always seem to think that "1-in-infinity" odds are very good and makes checking for errors pointless.